# Should an object belonging to an instance stay linked with the prototype?

Tags: javascript, prototype

What's the better?

This implementation

```
var Animal = function(){
     this.properties = {};
     for(var key in Animal.prototype.properties) this.properties[key] = Animal.prototype.properties[key];
};
Animal.prototype.properties = {
    name: 'animal'
};
```

Or this one

```
var AnimalV2 = function(){
    this.properties = Object.create(AnimalV2.prototype.properties);
};
AnimalV2.prototype.properties = {
    name: 'animalv2'
};
```

When I change the prototype property it only affects the second implementation.

```
var dog = new Animal()
var cat = new AnimalV2();

Animal.prototype.properties.name = 'hello world';
AnimalV2.prototype.properties.name = 'hello world';

console.log(dog.properties.name); // 'animal'    
console.log(cat.properties.name); // 'hello world'
```

As we can see dog.properties is no more linked with Animal.prototype.properties. Is it better in terms of performance or of code quality?

Comment: the question is not clear.what do you mean not linked?all you did is changing Animal.prototype.properties.name, but this doesn't affect other elements of properties

Comment: dog.properties is independant of his constructor.prototype.properties unlike cat.properties. The code try to show that changing constructor prototype after instantiation has different effect on dog and cat. My question is: which one is preferable?

Comment: * Do this with methods and the result will be diferent.

Comment: My question concerns objects. Should I write a constructor that instantiate objects without prototypal inheritance (Animal) or with (AnimalV2)

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the first case

```
var Animal = function(){
     this.properties = {};
     for(var key in Animal.prototype.properties)
         this.properties[key] = Animal.prototype.properties[key];
};
Animal.prototype.properties = {
     name: 'animal'
};
```

You are iterating over all properties and assigning them one by one so it will cost more as more properties are in Animal.prototype.properties, in the second one:

```
var AnimalV2 = function(){
     this.properties = Object.create(AnimalV2.prototype.properties);
};
AnimalV2.prototype.properties = {
     name: 'animalv2'
};
```

You are creating a new object and assigning it's [[Prototype]] property to AnimalV2.prototype.properties, so it's only one assignement doesn't matter how many properties does AnimalV2.prototype.properties have.

TL;DR
So looking at performace and elegancy, the second one is the better way.

In case of clean code I don't like anyone of those, I preffer to have properties always on the constructor and keep the prototype for methods, it's just simple for non-javascript programmers. (and it will also be faster)

```
AnimalV3 = function() {
    this.properties = {
       prop1: 'a',
       prop2: 'b'
    };
}
```